# installReactHook is not a function / installReactHook is undefined

Tags: ios, react-native

Suddenly I can't get my react native project to start on ios simulator or device. I don't know what happened in between. I tried to clear all  cache, reinstalled the node modules, pod install, but nothing works. Can't find anything except that in the react native documentation that this is part of Systrace. I'm stumped.

I did run `npm link` yesterday - maybe it messed something up, but still after that building was not an issue.

I'm sure i messed something up myself, but hopefully someone has a hint.

[image]

Comment: I also see this error `Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)`

Comment: commenting my progress: whilst checking if andoird build has similar problem, found this module (that i am not using, but is lingering in my package.json `react-native-animated-linear-gradient` gives problems with `ReactNativeFeatureFlags.js`, continuing to removing this package completely...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bit of a headache.

I also saw the error `Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)`. But that was not really the issue.

Whilst checking if android build has similar problem, I found that the module `react-native-animated-linear-gradient` had two issues

1. It gave problems with ReactNativeFeatureFlags.js.
2. It had a duplicate definition of `react-native` (as if it also included the whole react-native project through its package.json

By continuing to remove this package completely, unlinking it manually, reinstalling npm packages and cleaning my npm cache I finally got it to work again, both on android and ios.

I wasn't using that package, but due to lingering in my package.json and running `npm update` it went and broke something in my setup I suspect. If only I had removed it completely after not testing and deciding not using it.

I hope it helps people giving direction if you suddenly see installreacthook not found. It costs me 4 hours to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will help, but sometimes cleaning the ios build folder fixes weird things

[image]

Comment: Yep, tried that already indeed. unfortunately that wasn't it.